# How to sum up multiple lists in Prolog

Tags: prolog

This is a problem suma( [ [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ], [ 2, 3, 4, 5 ], [ 3, 4, 5, 6 ] ], X ), and i need to get this result X = [ 10, 14, 18 ]. I don't have any idea how to figure this out. Please help

Answer (score 1):

[`maplist/3`](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=maplist/4) and [`foldl/4`](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=foldl/4) and [yall notation](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=yall) (the last one available in SWI-Prolog) are your friends.

```
suma(ListOfLists,ListOfSums) :-
   maplist(
      ([Sublist,Sum]>>
          (foldl(
              [AccumIn,X,AccOut]>>(AccOut is AccumIn + X),
              Sublist,
              0,
              Sum))),
      ListOfLists,
      ListOfSums).
```

Thus:

```
?- suma( [ [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ], [ 2, 3, 4, 5 ], [ 3, 4, 5, 6 ] ], X ).
X = [10, 14, 18].
```

This is less logic programming than functional programming, but if one has a Swiss Army Knife, one might as well use it!

- `maplist/3`: Calls the goal that is on argument position 0 for every pair `[Sublist,Sum]` where `Sublist` is an element of the list on argument position 1 (i.e. `ListOfLists`) and `Sum` is an element of the list on argument position 2 (i.e. `ListOfSums`), both elements being at the same position in their respective lists.
- The goal called takes `[Sublist,Sum]` and calls `foldl/4`, which "folds-left" the list `Sublist` using the goal on argument position 0, starting with value 0 and resulting in value `Sum`.
- The folding operation is simply arithmetic addition via `[AccumIn,X,AccOut]>>(AccOut is AccumIn + X)`.

This can be more extensively written as:

```
suma(ListOfLists,ListOfSums) :-
   maplist(
      p2,            % will be called with 2 parameters
      ListOfLists,
      ListOfSums).

p2(Sublist,Sum) :-
   foldl(
      p3,            % will be called with 3 parameters
      Sublist,
      0,
      Sum).

p3(AccumIn,X,AccOut) :-
   AccOut is AccumIn + X.
```

We can run some [`plunit`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section(%27packages/plunit.html%27)) test cases for good measure (actually, the problem to solve should be *stated* with the below, [TDD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development) and all that):

```
:- begin_tests(sum_over_sublists).

test("empty list of lists",true(R == [])) :-
   suma([],R).

test("all sublists contain one value",true(R == [1,2,3])) :- 
   suma([[1],[2],[3]],R).
   
test("one sublist is empty",true(R == [1,0,3])) :- 
   suma([[1],[],[3]],R).
   
test("standard case #1",true(R == [6,15,24])) :- 
   suma([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]],R).
   
test("standard case #2",true(R == [10,14,18])) :-
   suma([[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,5],[3,4,5,6]],R).

:- end_tests(sum_over_sublists).
```

And so:

```
?- run_tests.
% PL-Unit: sum_over_sublists ..... done
% All 5 tests passed
true.
```

Comment: I also think Prolog needs a little extension to alternatively work in positional parameters and named parameters so that one could write `foldl(start=0,list=Sublist,result=Sum,goal=p3)` like one can do in rule chainers like CLIPS.

Comment: If you're committing to SWI anyway, you might as well use its `sum_list/2` (which should really be called `list_sum/2` to reflect the order of arguments).

Comment: @IsabelleNewbie "Committing" using `foldl/N`?

Comment: Yes, and using `library(yall)`. `maplist(sum_list, Xss, Sums)` is shorter than your solution and portable to at least GNU Prolog as well. Don't get me wrong, there's nothing wrong with showing off `library(yall)`! I just found it interesting that you're doing a bit too much of the work yourself in this particular case.

Answer (score -2):

```
%! sum(Xs,SUM)
%
% calculate the total sum of the items in list `Xs` .

sum(Xs,SUM)
:-
sum(Xs,0,SUM)
.

sum([],SUM0,SUM0) .

sum([X0|Xs],SUM0,SUM)
:-
SUM1 is SUM0 + X0 ,
sum(Xs,SUM1,SUM)
.
```

```
/*
?- sum([1,2,3,4],SUM).
SUM = 10.

?- sum([2,3,4,5],SUM).
SUM = 14.

?- sum([3,4,5,6],SUM).
SUM = 18.
*/
```

```
%! suma(Xss0,SUM)
%
% calculate the total sum of the items in list of lists `Xss` .

suma([],0) .

suma([Xs0|Xss0],SUM)
:-
sum(Xs0,SUM0) ,
suma(Xss0,SUM1) ,
SUM is SUM0 + SUM1
.
```

```
/*
?- suma([[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,5]],SUM).
SUM = 24.

?- suma([[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,5],[3,4,5,6]],SUM).
SUM = 42.
*/
```

Comment: But the result of the last example should be `[ 10, 14, 18 ]`, not `42`.  You have to sum over the sublists individually, not over all the elements of all the sublists.

Comment: @DavidTonhofer something has to be left for homework .